# Extract all lines from a text file that partial match keywords listed in another file

Tags: python, awk, extract, partial, lines

I have exhausted online searches trying to find out how to do this.

I have tab delimited file `searchfile.txt` with two columns and >200 rows. Sample here:

```
A(H1N1)/SWINE/COTES-DARMOR/388/2009 X?  4.28144245
A(H1N2)/SWINE/SCOTLAND/410440/1994 X?   7.25878836
A(H1)/SWINE/ENGLAND/117316/1986 X?  3.305392038
A(H1)/SWINE/ENGLAND/438207/1994 X?  7.66078717
```

I have another file `keywords.txt` with some keywords that partially match the IDs in `searchfile.txt`:

```
ENGLAND/117316    
DARMOR/388   
438207
```

I want to extract all lines from `searchfile.txt` that contain any of the keywords in `keywords.txt`

Using solutions from other similar questions I tried:

```
grep -F -f keywords.txt searchfile.txt > selected.txt 

grep -f keywords.txt searchfile.txt

awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0];next} ($NF in a)' keywords.txt searchfile.txt > result.txt
```

I also got part of the way there with this `python` script:

```
infile = r"/path/to/searchfile.txt"

results = []
to_keep = ["ENGLAND/117316",
            "DARMOR/388",
            "438207"]

with open(infile) as f:
    f = f.readlines()

for line in f:
    for phrase in to_keep:
        if phrase in line:
            results.append(line)
            break

print(results)
```

And it outputs this in the terminal window:

```
[
    'A(H1N1)/SWINE/COTES-DARMOR/388/2009 X?\t4.28144245\n',   
    'A(H1)/SWINE/ENGLAND/117316/1986 X?\t3.305392038\n', 
    'A(H1)/SWINE/ENGLAND/438207/1994 X?\t7.66078717\n'
]
```

Is there a way to

a) modify this script to read from a file like `keywords.txt` and output lines to another file? (My python skills are not up to that)

OR

b) use `grep`, `awk`, `sed`... to do this

I think the problem is that my keywords are not whole separate words and have to partially match what's in the `searchfile.txt`.

Grateful for any help! Thanks.

Comment: in `keywords.txt` You have blank characters at the end of the first two lines .... That's why `grep` doesn't works

Comment: Agree, the `grep -F -f ...` shouild work. Use `sed -i 's/  *$//' file` to remove spaces from your keywords.txt . Good luck.

Comment: Thanks both - the sed command needed to be  _sed -i ' ' 's/ *$//' file_  for reasons I don't quite understand. But I checked to make sure there weren't any blank spaces in my file (search and replace space with nothing in textwrangler). But still the output file is basically the whole input file! This is weird -- but the python script worked so problem solved for now.

Comment: If MS WIndows was involved in creation or moving (ftp, etc) of the file check for `\r\n` line endings with `cat -vet file` . If you see `^M$` at the end of lines, cleanup file with `dos2unix file`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward in python. Assuming you have `keywords.txt` and `input.txt` files and want to output to `output.txt`:

```
# 1
with open('keywords.txt', 'r') as k:
    keywords = k.read().splitlines()
    
#2
with open('input.txt') as f, open('output.txt', 'w') as o:
    for line in f:
        if any(key in line for key in keywords):
            o.writelines(line)
```

this reads in the keywords file, and stores each line from it in a list (#1). We then open our input and output text files, looping through the input file line-by-line and write to the output file if we find any of our keywords in the line (#2).

Comment: Thanks very much @asongtoruin! This works when I change 'wb' in line 8 to 'w' -- I gather it might be a python2 vs 3 thing...

Comment: @user2662391 think it might be an OS issue, my mistake. Edited to fix it now, glad to be of help :)